# How do I make a picture bigger?

Tags: images, resize

I have a picture of 100 x 100 (black and white) and I want to turn it into a 200 x 200 or 400 x 400 image, where each pixel is represented by a 2 x 2 or 4 x 4 square of black pixels.

Is there a way to do that using a Linux one-liner or a simple app available for Macs?

Answer (score 1):

Imagemagic is the tool for you. For 2x2 use

```
convert input.png -filter point -resize 200% output.png
```

for 4x4

```
convert input.png -filter point -resize 400% output.png
```

Done.